# Android WebView not loading image from assets on first time

Tags: android, xamarin, android-webview

When i open fragment with webView first time image (.bg css class) not loading, but every next open loaded correctly. Why?

*code html:*

```
<style>
...
 .bg
    {
        background: url('image.png') center center no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }
...
</style>
...
<body>
  <div class='bg'></div>
  <div class='content'>
  ...
  </div>
</body>
```

*code show html in fragment:*

```
_handler.Post(() => {                           
                    var settings = webView.Settings;
                    webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                    webView.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
                    settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
                    settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
                    settings.AllowContentAccess = true;
                    settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
                    settings.DefaultTextEncodingName = "utf-8";
                    webView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                    webView.LoadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
                });
```

**UPD:**
I think its not a concurrency issue, because if i move all code into ui thread and remove all webView visibility changes this bug continues to reproduce.

Comment: This seems like a concurrency issue. You probably show the web view before it was loaded on the first time and all your next loads already have the loaded data from the first load.  
If that is the case I would suggest sub-classing `WebViewClient`and overriding `OnPageFinished` to show the web view after it was loaded

Comment: Another thing, if you use `_handler.Post` you postpone the load for the next UI update, this shouldn't be an issue but I would try without `Post` just to be on the safe side

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue. not sure if it is the same case as yours.  I spent more than 3 days and found the cause it that another WebView object calls pauseTimers() for saving some CPU performance which actually " Pauses all layout, parsing, and JavaScript timers for all WebViews."